# NSURLConnection Results in BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c

I'm getting `BAD_ACCESS` when attempting to instantiate an `NSURLConnection` in a class that's called from my view controller.

I've implemented the delegate methods in the class, and the interface is a subclass of `NSObject <NSURLConnectionDelegate>`.

I can't for the life of me figure out what the problem is:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://valid-value-here"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init ];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request addValue:@"application/json;chartset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSString *myJSONString = @"valid-json-string";
NSData *myJSONData = [myJSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSUInteger cCount = [myJSONString length];
[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", cCount] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


[request setHTTPBody:myJSONData];

NSURLResponse *theResponse = [[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
NSError *theError = nil;

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

When the code hits the last line above, the exception occurs.

I'm a .Net developer most of the time, so my familiarity with XCode is sub-par, and I'm also relatively new to Objective-C, so any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**

Here is the output from the ZombieEnabled: *** -[AccountApi Login:password:onSuccess:onFail:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x71427c0

That is the method that this `NSURLConnection` lives inside.  It is called via:

```
loginApi = [[AccountApi alloc] init];

[loginApi Login: @"" password:@"" onSuccess:^{} onFail:^{}];
```

With `loginApi` declared as `AccountApi *loginApi;` above the `@implementation` for the view controller.

**Edit 2**
I've declared my reference to `AccountApi` as an instance variable via:

```
@implementation LoginViewController {
AccountApi *lApi;
}
```

Then in the function:

```
- (void)callApi
{

    lApi = [[AccountApi alloc] init];

    NSString *login = userLogin.text;

    NSString *pass = userPassword.text;

    [lApi Login: login password: pass onSuccess:^{
        [self successBlock];  // For example...
    } onFail:^{
        [self failBlock];  // For example...
    }];

}
```

This instantly still produces: 
*** -[AccountApi Login:password:onSuccess:onFail:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7154ba0

**Edit 3**
I've confirmed that `lApi` is already a zombie by the time it gets to the `Login` call.  How is it deallocating in 3 lines of code from: `lApi = [[AccountApi alloc] init];` to the call?

**Solved**
In `AccountApi` my init was missing something....ugh:
Was:

```
- (id)init {

}
```

Should be:

```
- (id)init {
return self;
}
```

Comment: It should be `NSUInteger cCount = [myJSONData length];` because the number of UTF-8 bytes can be different from the string length. And there is a typo in "chartset=utf-8".

Comment: Sometimes this indicates an object being over released but can also be caused by a variety of errors. Have you [enabled zombies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode)?

Comment: Is your code compiled with Automated Reference Counting?

Comment: Your error is not in the code you posted; this runs fine.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield It is compiled with ARC enabled.

Comment: @CarlVeazey, I just did (that was new to me).  I have updated the question with the information it supplied.

Comment: @AaronBrager, thanks for the sanity check!

Comment: Looks like by the time your success / fail block is called, `loginApi` has been deallocated.  Try storing `loginApi` in a property or instance variable.

Comment: What is `self` in `delegate:self`? The loginApi instance or something else?

Comment: @MartinR, it is the loginApi instance.

Comment: NSURLConnection retains its delegate until the connection is finished, so I wonder how that instance can be deallocated.

Comment: I've made another edit to show the calling code better.  Making it an instance variable didn't seem to help.